# Is i7 8565U, with 16 gb RAM, 512 SSD with intel uhd 620, only integrated good enough for Android studio?

Tags: video, web-development, video-editing, game-development

I would like to buy, HP Spectre x360 with intel i7 8565U, 16 gb RAM, 512gb ssd with intel uhd 620 but I am not sure If I will be able to run some app emulators for development, I will do some Programming and maybe some gaming as well but I am not intending to play games with intensive graphics like GTA5. Is it worth to buy, will it be enough?

Comment: Is it worth it questions are asking for an opinion, which don't really work with our QA format. Compatibility and Stability questions are also outside the scope of the site. Instead, please list out your requirements, budget, and use case(s) of the laptop, and we will find one that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using emulator, it will get better performance if you have a dedicated GPU... Its Good to have one, but its not a requirement, modern intel UHD graphics should be sufficient. ... Android app development doesn't require much of a GPU... but i always recommend to go for gaming laptops because they are specially designed for speed and high processing capabilities. Well HP spectre x360 is also among the best laptops on which you can rely blindly

Answer (score 1):

That should be good enough. I have a slightly worse laptop (aside from GPU) and it can run more intensive things like a Windows virtual machine or Unity game engine without a problem, so you should be fine.